# how to make image fixed in Pagepilling.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make fixed some objects in PagePilling.js. I try to make with CSS, HTML, JS. But it doesn't work. Any ideas? how to make fixed e.g. Logo or menu?

pagepilling example: http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/ 
and this is small example what I mean, this is fixed: jsfiddle.net/30ae2ftk

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed"?

Comment: position: fixed. if i scroll down, it must be fixed.

Comment: this is simple example what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/30ae2ftk/

Comment: Did you try setting the `menu` option?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late. And you would have found the solution already. If I understand your question correctly, you want to make the background image of each section fixed. In your CSS add this line to your section:

```
.section {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

And in your pagepiling initiator add `css3: false`, like this:

```
$('.section-container').pagepiling({ css3: false });
```

These should fix your issues.